# Search result in Symfony project with Elasticsearch

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, elastica, foselasticabundle

**Problem:**

I have the following problem. I'm able to search through my data with the SKU. But since there are multiple distributors I want to filter on SKU & distributor. But how can I do that, what I have so far is

**PHP**

```
$finder = $this->getContainer()->get('fos_elastica.finder.product.productstock');
$query = new \Elastica\Query\MultiMatch();
$query->setFields(["sku", "distributor"]);
$query->setQuery('XXXXXX');
$productStock = $finder->find($query);
dump($query);
dump($productStock);exit;
```

**$query** dump:

```
Elastica\Query\MultiMatch {#900
  #_params: array:2 [
    "fields" => array:2 [
      0 => "sku"
      1 => "distributor"
    ]
    "query" => "XXXXXXXX"
  ]
  #_rawParams: []
}
```

**Query** result:

```
array:2 [
  0 => AppBundle\Entity\ProductStock {#970
    -id: 16218
    -sku: "XXXXXX"
    -stock: 90
    -price: "11.00"
    -distributor: "XXX"
  }
  1 => AppBundle\Entity\ProductStock {#938
    -id: 54086
    -sku: "XXXXXX"
    -stock: 25
    -priceOverride: "11.00"
    -distributor: "XXX"   
  }
]
```

Database table ProductStock

```
+---+-----+------+--------+-------+
|id | sku |stock | vendor | price |
+---+-----+------+--------+-------+
```

My **goal** what I want to achieve is to get 1 array from my Elasticsearch result if the SKU and distributor has a match.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set type of the query :

```
$query->setType(self::TYPE_BEST_FIELDS);
$query->setOperator(self::OPERATOR_AND);
```

If this not work :

```
$query->setType(self::TYPE_MOST_FIELDS);
```

Explanation :

> The most_fields type is most useful when querying multiple fields that
>   contain the same text analyzed in different way

check more details [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-best-fields)

Comment: This still gives me multiple results which is not the idea. It should return 1 result since sku and distributor matches only 1 distributor.

Comment: add $query->setOperator(self::OPERATOR_AND);

Comment: Thx for your response and help so far. But the result from this is not the expected result. SKU & Distributor are two different columns in the database and If I am not wrong its not possible to search for both fields with two queries.